# How To Put HTML Code In Laravel Function?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I stumbled upon this problem. I am using twitter bootstrap. I generate form elements like this:

```
{{ Form::button('Save', array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) }}
```

This is alright. But when I want to put an icon before the 'Save' like this,

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="icon-ok"></i> Save', array('class'=>;'btn btn-success')) }}
```

> The <i> tag is not interpreted as it should be.
> Is there any workaround on this? How do I do this?
>
> Any Body Give Some Idea
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can solve it with css.

Comment: yes I can do this but laravel code must be important for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML::decode method to wrap your button.

Example:

`{{ HTML::decode(Form::button('<i class="icon-ok"></i> Save', array('class'=>;'btn btn-success'))) }}`

HTML::decode converts entities to HTML characters according to laravel's api, found here:
[laravel api](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/)

Comment: Thank you Very Much For Good Answer This Is properly Work In My Application So Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Laravel are you using?

In Laravel 5, Blade has changed so that {{ }} is escaped by default (therefore not rendered as HTML by the browser) and you should use {!! !!} instead.

Comment: I Am Using Laravel4.2